# Is there a better way to find out if an object is in a list in python?

Tags: list, python-3.x

In python I want to make a function that returns true if something is inside a list. Here is my example code.

```
def isin(List, value):
    try:
        i = List.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

For example in if I do

```
myList = [0,1,'string', 4.8]

isin(myList, 1) # I want to return True
isin(myList, 'animal') # I want to return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
if 1 in myList         # true
if "animal" in myList  # false
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has the `in` operator built-in for that:

```
myList = [0,1,'string', 4.8]

if 1 in myList:
    # Do something
    pass 

print('animal' in myList) # Prints 'False'.
```